# Background size cover is not working

Tags: html, css, background-size

My PNG picture size is 1000px by 1000px.
I use it as a background image in a DIV which has a height of 550px and a `background-size: cover` property.

My issue is that this background-size cover does not seem to be working. My picture is not scaled down to the size of the DIV. What is the issue?

[image]

Comment: It is always better to post the code or a demo than a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your actual code, answers can only be based on assumptions but I am assuming that my assumption must be correct in this case based on the screenshot provided.

From the screenshot, it seems like your element doesn't have a fixed width and is taking up 100% of the available width and also that the ***width is a lot higher compare to the height*** of the element.

(*The above assumption has been confirmed by your live link.*)

---

As per specs, the `cover` keyword has the following definition:

> ***cover***
>
> A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and ***maintains image aspect ratio*** (image doesn't get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container. ***When the image and container have different dimensions, the image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom.***

The key parts that are relevant for this question have been emphasized. As you have indicated, in this case, the image's dimensions is 1000 x 1000 whereas the container's dimensions is ***[Y]*** x 550 where ***[Y]*** seems to be higher than 550. Now, let us assume that ***[Y]*** is 750. This would mean that the image will be scaled such that it has to fit the entire width (as it is larger). Since image has 1:1 aspect ratio, it would be scaled down to 750 x 750. Thus the image's height is greater than the container's height and so the bottom part of the image will get cropped.

You can see that in the below snippet also. The first image is the background with `cover` whereas the second is the actual sized image.

```css
div {
  height: 550px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nature/1);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nature/1' />
```

You can use `background-size: 100% 100%`, it will make the image fill the entire height and width of the container but it will not preserve/maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

Alternately, you could make use of `background-size: contain`, it would preserve the aspect ratio but it will leave white space on the left and right if the width is larger (or) on the top and bottom if the height is larger.

**Demo with width being larger:**

```css
div {
  height: 550px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nature/1);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nature/1' />
```

**Demo with height being larger:**

```css
div {
  height: 550px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nature/1);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 450px;
  /* just for demo */
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nature/1' />
```

Comment: Thanks Harry. Unfortunately that does not work with my image (it does however work with a landscape picture). I have added to my post the link to the live example if you have time to have a look. Many thanks

Comment: @Greg: Sorry, didn't quite understand which option didn't work for you. Was it the `contain` or `100% 100%`? As mentioned in my answer (after the edit), if you want aspect ratio to be preserved and image to not be cropped then your best bet is `contain`. Else, if aspect ratio doesn't matter then use `100% 100%`. If aspect ratio should be maintained and image shouldn't be cropped then either change the `div` or the image to have the same aspect ratio as the other. There are no other options as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, "contain" is what I needed. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Use background-size 100% 100% instead, should solve the issue.