# background image clipping large screens

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image. On large screens it clips off the bottom and top. Is there a way around this without distorting the image?

```
.bg {
width:100%;
height:550px;
background: url(http://snorm.co/nar6336%20mar15%20v2/assets/img-dist/test.png);
background-size: cover;
background-position-x: bottom;
background-position-y: center;
}
```

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/jakepeg/pen/zqjeJN)

Comment: Have a look at this answer and see if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529591/background-size-cover-is-not-working/36529800#36529800